# How to specify a namespace for XML::child()?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, e4x

The function `XML::child()` accepts an Object parameter to specify the name of the child element(s) to be obtained.
But there's seemingly no way to specify a namespace should there be one.
I even tried `XML::setNamespace()` and `default xml namespace` but didn't work either.
I worked around this using E4X, but it's not my preferred option.

XML:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d= "..." />
  <anotherElement />
  <path d="..." />
</svg>
```

AS:

```
var svg: XML = new XML( svgData ); // read from the XML file above
var ns: Namespace = new Namespace( "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" );
svg.setNamespace( ns ); // doesn't seem to help
default xml namespace = ns; // doesn't help either
var child:* = svg.child( "path" ); // how to specify namespace?
var child2:* = svg.ns:path; // works, but I'd rather use the XML class API
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to use the namespace for? I can't understand what's your 'preferred option', as `svg.ns::path` works properly..

Comment: I don't want to use the namespace, I have to, SVG files have to have that namespace.
There's not much to understand, I've tried the E4X solution, I know it works, I'm just curious about the other way, as it should work with any XML, with or without namespaces, but the documentation doesn't seem to address this.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried it with `use namespace ns;` but that didn't help either. But `default xml namespace = ns` **does** help after all:

```
        var svg:XML = 
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path d= "..." />
              <anotherElement />
              <path d="..." />
            </svg>;  

        var ns: Namespace = new Namespace( "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" );

        default xml namespace = ns; // helps after all
        var child:XML = svg.child( "path" )[0];

        trace(child.toXMLString());
        // -> outputs <path d="..." xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"/>
```

`svg.child("path")` gives an XMLList containing both `<path ... />` entries; I just changed your code to output only the first item.

I've tried this in Flash Builder 4.7 with AIR SDK 3.8

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with `default` namespace, for such task you could use `default xml namespace` directive:

```
var myNamespace:Namespace = new Namespace("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
default xml namespace = myNamespace;

//dealing with XML

default xml namespace = "";
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote in the question: `default xml namespace = ns; // doesn't help either`